# How to Read JSON Result with blank root name FROM API - XCODE11 (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Sample JSON DATA

```
[ { "Active": "39", "BillingProperty": null, "DAS": "test_user|aman|LINEMANUSER", "Entity": "dendb", "GULCOCode": "M000100010000100001000000420", "Inactive": "572", "LCOCode": "TEST-HO", "LcoCategory": "Prepaid", "Status": "M000100010000100001000004848", "Success": "1", "Total": "0", "alcrights": "1", "freshActivation": "1", "profileexist": "1", "promorights": "1", "staffID": null, "userID": "M000100010000100001000004848", "walletBalance": 0.35 } ]
```

```
================================= 
what i have tried so far !! 
=================================
```

```
struct MyClass :Codable 
{ 
    var Status: String 
}

let session = URLSession.shared session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in 
    do { let countries=try JSONDecoder().decode(MyClass.self, from : data!) 
        print(countries.Status)  
    } 
    catch { 
       print ("error"); 
    } 
}.resume()
```

Comment: Note that your JSON has an _array_ as its root.

Comment: yes inside array only values are coming . root does't has name . kinly help in reading the status out of that

Comment: hi . mentioned in question

Comment: There is no *blank* root, it's just an unkeyed array. So decode an array: `[MyClass].self`. And **never** print completely meaningless literal string `"error"`, print the real thrown `error`

Answer (score 1):

try this: (i recommend using this site: https://app.quicktype.io/)

```
// This file was generated from JSON Schema using quicktype, do not modify it directly.
// To parse the JSON, add this file to your project and do:
//
// let welcome = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)


import Foundation

// MARK: - WelcomeElement
struct WelcomeElement: Codable {
    let active: String
    let billingProperty: JSONNull?
    let das, entity, gulcoCode, inactive: String
    let lcoCode, lcoCategory, status, success: String
    let total, alcrights, freshActivation, profileexist: String
    let promorights: String
    let staffID: JSONNull?
    let userID: String
    let walletBalance: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case active = "Active"
        case billingProperty = "BillingProperty"
        case das = "DAS"
        case entity = "Entity"
        case gulcoCode = "GULCOCode"
        case inactive = "Inactive"
        case lcoCode = "LCOCode"
        case lcoCategory = "LcoCategory"
        case status = "Status"
        case success = "Success"
        case total = "Total"
        case alcrights, freshActivation, profileexist, promorights, staffID, userID, walletBalance
    }
}

typealias Welcome = [WelcomeElement]

// MARK: - Encode/decode helpers

class JSONNull: Codable, Hashable {

    public static func == (lhs: JSONNull, rhs: JSONNull) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    public var hashValue: Int {
        return 0
    }

    public init() {}

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if !container.decodeNil() {
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(JSONNull.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for JSONNull"))
        }
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        try container.encodeNil()
    }
}
```

Comment: @VinodSaini i just edited the answer. Chris is the one who answered. Accept the answer if it worked :)